# Symfony - token

Tags: mysql, function, api, symfony, token

I wrote a query and a function but I can't pass this logic. I need to write a statement where I it can not generate same token value again when it post to database.

```
public function getToken($user, $token)
{
    $tok = $this->getRepository()
        ->createQueryBuilder('pt')
        ->select('pt')
        ->where('pt.user = :user')
        ->andWhere('pt.token = :token')
        ->setParameter('user', $user)
        ->setParameter('token', $token)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();

    if(empty($token)) {
        $tok = new Token();
        $tok->setUser($user);
        $tok->setToken($token);
        $this->em->persist($tok);
        $this->em->flush();
    }

    return $tok;
}
```

and in my controller..

```
public function getTokenAction()
{
    $this->requirePostParams(['user', 'token']);

    $this->get('token')->getToken($this->getUser(), $this->data['token']);

    return $this->success();
}
```

So, if that token value is in the db, not to post it again and if it's not, then yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that you only create a new Token when the *parameter* $token is empty, not when the *object* $tok is empty.

Simply replace `if(empty($token))` by `if(empty($tok))`

You should also replace `->getResult()` by `->getOneOrNullresult()` since you only want one object token, not an array.

Comment: That's the case! Thanks a lot.